# How to fix ForgotPassword page opening with pass user logged in information

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

When I am opening the forgot password page, it will show infromation in the navbar that is linked to the user that was previously logged in with that computer. It loads the page as if it still has a UserRole to show other information that someone without a userRole should not see.

I have tried

```
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  Roles.DeleteCookie();
  Session.Clear();
```

and non of this seems to work.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
{   
  AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
  return View();
}
```

It should just show the basic change password page.